# What are (some of) the best resources for shift scheduling/rostering?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, reference-request, scheduling

Shift scheduling/rostering is obviously very widely researched, with tons of papers around it. I found the review papers by Van den Bergh *et al.* [1] and Ernst *et al.* [2], but am looking for something that actually shows the various types of math models that have been used for this with the relevant extensions.

Could you please point me to the relevant books/book chapters/papers for this? Thanks!

---

[1] Van den Berg, J.; Beliën, J.; De Bruecker, P.; Demeulemeester, E.; De Boeckab, L. Personnel scheduling: A literature review. [EJOR](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0377221712008776).

[2] Ernst, A. T.; Jiang, H.; Krishnamoorthy, M.; Sier, D. Staff scheduling and rostering: A review of applications, methods and models. [EJOR](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S037722170300095X).

Comment: If this is for research, I guess you could start with the latest formulations such as those proposed in [Romer, 2021](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3798667) and [Lai et al, 2020](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejor.2019.12.019) which outperform the previous formulations.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, we've been gathering a bunch of [Design Patterns in chapter 20 of OptaPlanner's User Guide](https://docs.optaplanner.org/8.11.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#domainModelingGuide). Here are some of the drawings:

[image]
[image]

There's also [a video that explains this deeper](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0uAoWU8m0pE).

Besides these modeling basics, there are orthogonal features to consider (document in other places in the user guide):

- Pinning: allow the user to lock in a shift assignment to an employee, before solving (so the solver has to work around it)
- Continuous planning: every week publish the schedule 3 weeks in advance, don't paint yourself in a corner, ...
- Non-disruptive replanning: making changes on a published schedule
- Publishing, fairness constraints, rotation schedules, ...

A drawing of Continuous Planning with Rotation:

[image]

And there's [a video to explain these advanced topics](https://youtu.be/Ew6pq9nJKog) too.

These patterns are illustrated in 2 implementations:

- [optaplanner-example's nurse rostering](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/tree/main/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/nurserostering) (based on the International Nurse Rostering Competition specs)
- [optaweb-employee-rostering](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaweb-employee-rostering) a full blown webapp

that have been the basis for production deployments across the globe.

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey, this looks very interesting. However, I was more looking for the mathematical formulation underlying the rostering. Do you have any material for that?

Comment: For fair distribution of shifts across employees, [here's my blog post discussing different mathematical formula on quantifying the penalty](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2017/02/03/FormulaForMeasuringUnfairness.html).

Comment: Beyond that, we don't accept constraints as mathematical equations, but as OO/FP code, so others - using more traditional solvers - will be able to help for you better with that.